# how can I run a playboook on a single or short list of hosts and getting content from a inventory group where the host is not part of?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I do have a playbook which tooks a specific group and put all hosts of this group into a command on another host.

to be more precise.
all hosts from the hosts group oldservers from my inventory file must be in the /etc/ssh.conf on one or multiple clients.

the task looks like...

```
---

- name: echo Old Servers
  debug:
    var: groups["oldservers"]

- name: create ssh_conf_for_old_server 
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    backup: True
    block: |
      Host {{ groups["oldservers"]|join(' ') }}
        user admin
        KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
        HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
        Ciphers +aes128-cbc
```

this should be executed on a client which is not member of the group servers.

hosts file (inventory):

```
[clients]
192.168.200.1
192.168.200.2

[oldservers]
192.168.201.1
192.168.201.2
```

My execution line is ansible-playbook -i 192.168.200.1,  -u ansible ./createServerList.yml

I guess I should do it a bit different. Dont I ?

The result should be ... at first output all the oldservers (debug)
than write a block with these old server into the /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question fully or correct, but you may be looking for [delegation to other hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393428/) and [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html).

Comment: hope that edit makes things more clear

Answer (score 1):

For command `ansible-playbook -i 192.168.200.1 -u ansible ./createServerList.yml`, you are passing the ip address directly as inventory. Because of this Ansible is unaware of the inventory file where host groups are defined. So can you try running this instead `ansible-playbook -i <path_to_inventory_file> -u ansible ./createServerList.yml`

And then if you have to restrict playbook running only certain hosts or group, do

- `ansible-playbook -i <path_to_inventory_file> -u ansible ./createServerList.yml --limit "192.168.200.1,192.168.200.2"`

**OR**

- `ansible-playbook -i <path_to_inventory_file> -u ansible ./createServerList.yml --limit clients`